# PHP Encrypt mailaddress with same output

Tags: php, encryption

I'm trying to safely store email addresses in a database, but need to check if a specific email address is already in that database. My current encrypting with openssl_encrypt (I used the example on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) will output a different output every time I refresh the page. That way I cannot check if the given email address (stored as encrypted string in the database) is already in that database; I don't want to decrypt them all and use a foreach loop to check existence.

Is there a secure way of storing the email addresses, but where I'm able to quickly check the existance? Thanks!

**Edit:**
I think a bit more context is needed. I added the underneath additionaly:

MD5 is not secure for a while now. If my database is hacked, I don't want those email addresses saved in a unsecure hash method.

The application is to register yourself when a product is not in stock. When the product is back in stock, all the registered persons should receive an email. So I do need to decrypt the email addresses again to send the email to.
Now the issue is that when a person is already registered, I want to prevent registering twice and give feedback that they already registered. To prevent decrypting all registered email addresses and then check if one of those is trying to register, I want to do something like "select * from table where emailhashed = '*HashedEmail*'". With openssl-encrypt I get different HashedEmail outputs so that doesn't work. The result will be zero and the registering continues resulting in a duplicate (triple, etcetera) registration.

Comment: `MD5` is an easy solution

Comment: @shirshak007 it's also obsolete and not secure any more, which defeats the point of using it in this case.

Comment: @ADyson MD5 is unsuitable for _cryptographic_ purposes, but I think that it's a bit of a stretch to claim that it's unsuitable for use as a surrogate key in this case. But if OP wants to appease even the most skittish of internet commentators there are plenty of other hash algorithms that don't cause knee-jerk reactions. Eg: SHA256.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about [security.se]. You could try AES-(GCM-)SIV. Using a hash is not advised as an adversary can guess the mail address and verify their guess using the hash value.

Comment: @Sammitch is the OP not asking what to use to encrypt their email addresses? What have I missed? It could also be mentioned that md5 is technically for hashing, not encryption. Is the idea to hash the email additionally and just match the hash to check for the existence of the email? Perhaps that's what I hadn't appreciated before

Comment: For clarity, the suggestion is to keep the encryption as-is with OpenSSL and add another field to contain the hash for lookups, indexing, or what-have-you.

Comment: @ADyson, I added some additional context. But as I'm typing the additional text, my gut feeling says that using the best hashing conflicts with my goal??